# How to get rid of the default page numbering when using `fancyhdr`

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I want to put my page numbering at the right bottom by using `\rfoot` in `fancyhdr`, but everytime I use it, the default page numbering appears at the central bottom which makes the page having two page numbering at a time. Does anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to tell fancyhdr that you want nothing in the "central field"

```
\cfoot{}\rfoot{\thepage}
```