# fancyfoot page numbering is overwriten at TOC and List of Fig pages

Tags: page-numbering, fancyhdr

I want to have the page numbers on the left of even and right of odd pages. So I did the following

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\cfoot{}
```

This works fine for all pages except table of content and list of figures. On those two pages the number is still at the center of the footer. How can I fix it?

PS. My question bit similar to the question [How to get rid of the default page numbering when using `fancyhdr`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20309/how-to-get-rid-of-the-default-page-numbering-when-using-fancyhdr) but not the same.

Comment: Although `esdd` already provided a solution, please post a MWE in order to compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no MWE in the question but I guess that you have to redefine the pagestyle `plain`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage} 
\cfoot{}

% redefine page style plain
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\blinddocument
\begin{figure}%
\fbox{Figure}
\caption{caption}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```